# this.props.history don't redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know where I'm going wrong
by clicking the enter button I validate my user and use this.props.history.push ("/ home");
and it doesn't work

my login . js

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            login:'',
            password:'',
        };
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
    async onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const {login, password } = this.state;

        const response = await api.post('/login', { login,password });
        const user = response.data.user.login;
        const {jwt} = response.data;

        localStorage.setItem('token', jwt);
        localStorage.setItem('user', user);
        this.props.history.push("/home");
    }
    onChange(e){
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

  render() {
    const { errors, login, password, isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="login">Login</label>
            <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value={login}  onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} placeholder="Informe seu login" />
            <label htmlFor="password">Senha</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}   placeholder="Informe sua senha"/>
        <button className="btnEnt" type="submit">Entrar</button>
    </form>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

my router . js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from './pages/login/index';
import DashBoard from './pages/dashboard/index';
import PrivateRoute from './auth';

export default function Routes(){
    console.log('a')
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute path="/home" component = {DashBoard}/>              
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}                <PrivateRoute path="/home" component = {DashBoard}/>              
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

my auth . js :

```
import { Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

const isAuth = () => {
    console.log('a');
    if(localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => 
            isAuth() ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ): (
                <Redirect
                to={{
                    pathname: '/',
                    state: {message: 'Usuário não autorizado'}
                }}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
}
export default PrivateRoute;
```

my dashboard / index

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from '../../components/Home';

```
class DashBoard extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
          <Home />
      )
    }
  }

  export default DashBoard;
```

error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of
>   undefined
>   Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of
>   undefined I really do not know what I can is wrong is not redirecting,
>   I have tried all possible alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use history in your React component, you need to wrap it in withRouter.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Answer (score 0):

```
    import history from 'add your path'
    export default function Routes() {
      console.log('a')
      return (
        <BrowserRouter history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={DashBoard} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )
    }
```

do changes in router file

```
 import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
 export default withRouter(LoginForm);
```

add withRouter in this component

Comment: Hello thanks i didn't understand what would be the path here
 import history from 'add your path'

Comment: and which file I would put:
export default withRouter (LoginForm);?

Comment: you have to add history npm and create history.js file and use it here by importing